# English Sentences to FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have the following 2 sentences to convert to FOL formulas-:

1) Water, water, everywhere, but not a drop to drink. **[ water(l) means water
is at location l, drinkable(l) means there is drinkable water at location l ]**

2) There's one in every class. **[ enrolled(x, c) means x is a student in class c;
one(x) means x is the "one" in question ]**

I have the following understanding

**Sentence 1**

Water is everywhere and none of that is drinkable

Translated as-: ∀l(water(l) ^ ¬drinkable(l))

**Sentence 2**

In all classes c, there exists one student

Translated as-: ∀c∃x(one(x) ⇒ enrolled(x,c))

Could you please help me if I have made an error somewhere. I am unsure if these are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct, the second is not.

Note that you can make $\forall c \exists x (one(x) \to enrolled(x,c))$ trivially true by (for every class $c$) picking an $x$ for which $one(x)$ is false ... as that will make the conditional true.

Indeed, it should not be that for every class there is someone such that *if* that is the 'one', then that 'one' is enrolled in the class ... but rather that for every class there is someone who is 'the one' *and* is enrolled in the class. So:

$\forall c \exists x (one(x) \land enrolled(x,c))$

Also, your

> In all classes c, there exists one student

is not right. It should be:

> In all classes c, there exists one student who is 'the one'